# message passing in a Google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There are a few questions about this but none met my needs. I have created an extension and I am trying to communicate between a content script and my options.html. I have been trying to use the `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` and the `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and neither work at all. No commands are executed or anything. Here is my code:

content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({command:value}, function(response) {});
```

options.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("in onRequest request.command = " + request.command);
    decide_command(trim(request.value));
    sendResponse({});
});
```

none of the alerts are executed and none of the functions are executed. I even tried using the example in the messaging API page and it didn't trigger any alerts or anything. I have tried a bunch of different combinations like putting the extension ID in the sendRequest to make sure its going to the right place, I have excluded the sendResponse to make sure it wasn't ending too quick. I have debug alerts all over and none get triggered except for the ones before and after the send request command in my content script. So I would assume it either gets executed and fails or something like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been working on this for days.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `options.html` as your `background_page` in manifest.json? I'm not sure if content scripts can communicate with options pages. Also, `request.value` looks like it's undefined.

Comment: yeah sorry that was an issue with testing that actually is request.command not request.value I changed some of the variable names in my code. Also there exists the same onRequest.addListener in my background page so one of them should get it. (I would hope)

Comment: https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html#simple

that is a link to the code I was using as a reference. I actually even added that code to my pages in order to see if anything was working. It didn't :[

I don't know if it has to do with permissions or something because I think I have the correct permissions in my manifest.json but can't be sure the page does not specify a certain requirement.

Comment: Perhaps something else is receiving the request before your option page? AKA, the background page?

Comment: well the background page is told to alert also and sent the command to the correct function so I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Chris noted an issue already: an extension's option page isn't running all the time, and is therefore not available to receive or generate messages. Background pages are better for this sort of communication, as they're always running, always available, and therefore always capable of responding to messages.

I'd suggest reworking your extension's architecture a bit such that the content script gathers relevant information and sends it to the background page. When the options page is opened, it can request the state from the background page. The background page is then responsible for maintaining state in a reasonable way, and for pushing information back and forth between the other pieces of your extension.

Does that make sense?

Comment: yeah I understand what you mean... I will try that either today or tomorrow... Neither the background page nor the options page responded when I had the addListener in them. Maybe because it was in both it wasn't doing the right thing?